# A theorem on semisimple ring doesn't hold on semisimple module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

All rings are with unity but not necessarily commutative.

We know that if a ring $R$ is left semisimple (a direct sum of minimal left ideals), 
then it is left artinian.

My question is: if an unital $R$-module $_R M$ is semisimple (a direct sum of simple $R$-submodule of $_R M$), 
is $_R M$ left artinian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no direct relationship: you can take any simple module $S$ and then $\oplus_{i\in \mathbb N} S$ is semisimple but not Artinian.

Over a field every module is semisimple, but the only Artinian ones are the finitely generated ones.

Comment: Thanks. You are always like my mentor when I am learning algebra.

Comment: @bfhaha Glad to be able to help!